# Is there a way to display a menu of 2 or 3 items to execute when you long press on the main icon of a flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter to develop iOS and Android apps.  I need to display a small menu when the user does a LONG PRESS on the app icon to perform 2 or 3 of the most common methods.  I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** 
please use package quick_actions https://pub.dev/packages/quick_actions 
please reference https://medium.com/flutter-community/quick-actions-in-flutter-c455caa4f2ba 
github for reference document https://github.com/SubirZ/quick_action

document reference demo

[image]

official example demo

[image]

official example code

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quick_actions/quick_actions.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Quick Actions Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String shortcut = "no action set";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final QuickActions quickActions = QuickActions();
    quickActions.initialize((String shortcutType) {
      setState(() {
        if (shortcutType != null) shortcut = shortcutType;
      });
    });

    quickActions.setShortcutItems(<ShortcutItem>[
      // NOTE: This first action icon will only work on iOS.
      // In a real world project keep the same file name for both platforms.
      const ShortcutItem(
        type: 'action_one',
        localizedTitle: 'Action one',
        icon: 'AppIcon',
      ),
      // NOTE: This second action icon will only work on Android.
      // In a real world project keep the same file name for both platforms.
      const ShortcutItem(
          type: 'action_two',
          localizedTitle: 'Action two',
          icon: 'ic_launcher'),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('$shortcut'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('On home screen, long press the app icon to '
            'get Action one or Action two options. Tapping on that action should  '
            'set the toolbar title.'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good but I'm needing the long press on the APP ICON from the mobile device - wanting to give the user the ability to LONG PRESS on the Icon and give them a menu of quick choices to perform - so not in the app itself but on the APP ICON before the app is actually run,

Comment: I have updated my answer, please use package quick action